# Sending dataframes within list to a plot function

Tags: r, list, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm trying to make multiple ggplot charts from multiple data frames. I have developed the code below but the final loop doesn't work.

```
df1 <- tibble(
  a = rnorm(10),
  b = rnorm(10)
)

df2 <- tibble(
  a = rnorm(20),
  b = rnorm(20)
)

chart_it <- function(x) {
  x %>% ggplot() +
    geom_line(mapping = aes(y=a,x=b)) +
    ggsave(paste0(substitute(x),".png"))
}

ll <- list(df1,df2)

for (i in seq_along(ll)) {
 chart_it(ll[[i]])
}
```

I know its something to do with

```
ll[[i]]
```

but I dont understand why because when I put that in the console it gives the dataframe I want.  Also, is there a way do this the tidyverse way with the map functions instead of a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to see two files called `df1.png` and `df2.png` at the end.

You need to somehow pass on the names of the dataframes to the function. One way of doing it would be through named list, passing the name along with the content of the list element.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

df1 <- tibble(
  a = rnorm(10),
  b = rnorm(10)
)

df2 <- tibble(
  a = rnorm(20),
  b = rnorm(20)
)

chart_it <- function(x, nm) {
  p <- x %>% ggplot() +
    geom_line(mapping = aes(y=a,x=b))
  ggsave(paste0(nm,".png"), p, device = "png")
}

ll <- list(df1=df1,df2=df2)

for (i in seq_along(ll)) {
  chart_it(ll[[i]], names(ll[i]))
}
```

In tidyverse you could just replace the loop with the following command without modifying the function.

```
purrr::walk2(ll, names(ll),chart_it)
```

or simply

```
purrr::iwalk(ll, chart_it)
```

There's also `imap` and `lmap`, but they will leave some output in the console, which is not what you would like to do, I guess.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `chart_it` function. It doesn't return a `ggplot`. Try saving the result of the pipe into a variable and `return()` that (or place it as the last statement in the function).

Something along the lines of

```
chart_it <- function(x) {
  chart <- x %>% ggplot() +
    geom_line(mapping = aes(y=a,x=b))

    ggsave(paste0(substitute(x),".png")) # this will save the last ggplot figure

    return(chart)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I run `chart_it(df1)` it saves the plot, so doesn't that mean my function is ok?

Comment: Tried the following 
    `chart_it <- function(x) {
      x %>% ggplot() +
        geom_line(mapping = aes(y=a,x=b)) +
        ggsave(paste0(substitute(x),".png")) -> chart
      return(chart)
    }`

And I get "Error: `device` must be NULL, a string or a function."